# 1:1 mapping from integer list into character list into python

Tags: python-3.x, string, integer, mapping, fingerprint

I am using finger print sensor where for each finger enroll I got a unique integer.
So i just want to name each number to a person name whose finger is scanned.

For example
List_number=[1,2,3,4,5]
This list contain the number assign by the finger print sensor.
List_Name= [sam, rohan, anny, missing, anthony]

This are the name of persons whose finger is enrolled & correspond number is result from sensor output as in List_number.
So when I deploy the finger print sensor. So I'll be able to name the person tooo... Not just number

Comment: Create a dictionary: `d = dict(zip(List_number, List_Name))` then `d[3]` will give you `anny`.

Comment: Sir  I tried the above code. The problem I am facing is that the list_number which I am getting is not in the list form, it is in the Result form which came out of the finger print sensor in terms of integer. When a person put his finger on the sensor

Comment: I have no idea what "Result form" means. Care to elaborate?